# csrf failed while uploading the file through swagger

Tags: django, swagger-ui

I am trying to upload an image file using swagger it throws

> {
>     "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
>     }

. It is important to mention that i'm using django-rest-swagger version 0.3.0 and django version 1.7.

YAML for uploading a picture looks like:

> ```
> parameters:
>     - name: image
>       in: formData
>       required: true
>       type: file
>     - name: caption
>       required: true
>       type: string
> ```

I don't want to use @csrf_exempt. I tried to pass a header into this but that didn't work. header was something like:

> ```
>     - name: X-CSRF-Token
>       description: csrftoken to be passed in header
>       in: header
>       required: true
>       type: string
> ```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the CSRF token tag in your HTML?

Comment: Did you figure this issue out?  I'm having the identical problem. It's only an issue for the api that has the file upload.  All other api endpoints work fine.

Comment: I don't know much that is going on with swagger and yaml, but what I see is that you are passing the csrf token as a header. It needs to be passed with the formdata only. name: csrfmiddlewaretoken value: get from either cookie or the form inputs

Comment: Experienced a similar problem to this where it turned out that I'd returned a Context instance not a RequestContext - so it couldn't access the csrf token which is stored on the session.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, if you're up to date with Django, it's just a misnamed header.

Use 'X-CSRFToken' instead of 'X-CSRF-Token', that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, i'm not understand about swagger so..

if you are using html and jquery on your front-end view,
you can use this when, post your data.

```
w.getCsrfToken = function () {
    // Extract CSRF token from cookies
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
        csrf_token = null;
    $.each(cookies, function (index, cookie) {
        var cookieParts = $.trim(cookie).split('=');
        if (cookieParts[0] === 'csrftoken') {
            csrf_token = cookieParts[1];
        }
    });
    return csrf_token;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about swagger, but when using jquery ajax I always use this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Acess CSRF token in the template.

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Access that token in the JavaScript template.

```
const token = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
```

Include it in the headers before making a call to the API.

```
headers:{'X-CSRFToken': token}
```

Hope it will resolve the error.

Answer (score -1):

remove the whole csrv problem edit the views

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

@csrf_protect
def any_function(request):
    csrfContext = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('htmlpage', csrfContext)
```